# Function called with onsubmit not returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a registration form with several inputs fields. I scan through between them, and if I find an input value with a value of "" I set the returnFalse variable to 1. At the end of the script I examine if that variable is 1, if yes, return false. But it doesn't seem to return false, even though the variable's value is clearly 1.

```
var emptyFieldScanner = function(){

/********************/
/*First name
/*******************/
if($("input#first_name").val() == ""){
    $("div#first_name_check").fadeIn();
    $("div#first_name_check").html("<span class='error'>Please enter your first name</span>");
    $("input#first_name").click(function(){
        $("div#first_name_check").fadeOut();
    });

    returnFalse = 1;
}
/*******************/

/********************/
/*Last name
/*******************/
if($("input#last_name").val() == ""){
    $("div#last_name_check").fadeIn();
    $("div#last_name_check").html("<span class='error'>Please enter your last name</span>");
    $("input#last_name").click(function(){
        $("div#last_name_check").fadeOut();
    });

    returnFalse = 1;
}
/*******************/

if(returnFalse == 1){
    return false;
}

}
```

But of course, if I put return = false at the start of the function it works:

```
var emptyFieldScanner = function(){
return false;
```

Form tag:

```
<form id="registration" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return emptyFieldScanner();">
```

I have no idea why it is not working, I have used the same structure several times. My question is, why isn't the function returning false?

Thank you very much!

Comment: are you sure your returnFalse is 1? did you debug?

Comment: What if all your fields are invalid except the last one?  I think you need to re-evaluate your logic here

Comment: Is `returnFalse` supposed to be a global variable? What happens if you init it with `var returnFalse = 0;` at the beginning of the function

Comment: How could I be so... Of course it is not working, because I forgot to declare the returnFalse variable (to 0) at the start of the function. Thank you!

Comment: What external scripts you are currently using in this web form ?